# Rotate a raster in Python

Tags: python, raster

I rotate a raster with follow code:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import rasterio
from affine import Affine  # For easly manipulation of affine matrix
from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling
import numpy as np


def get_center_pixel(dataset):
    """This function return the pixel coordinates of the raster center
    """
    width, height = dataset.width, dataset.height
    # We calculate the middle of raster
    x_pixel_med = width // 2
    y_pixel_med = height // 2
    return (x_pixel_med, y_pixel_med)

def rotate(inputRaster, angle, scale=1, outputRaster=None):
    outputRaster = 'rotated.tif' if outputRaster is None else outputRaster

    ### Read input
    source = rasterio.open(inputRaster)
    print(source.count)
    #assert source.crs == 'EPSG:4326', "Raster must have CRS=EPSG:4326, that is unprojected lon/lat (degree) relative to WGS84 datum"

    ### Rotate the affine about a pivot and rescale
    pivot = get_center_pixel(source)
    #pivot = None
    print("\nPivot coordinates:", source.transform * pivot)
    new_transform = source.transform * Affine.rotation(angle, pivot) * Affine.scale(scale)

    # this is a 3D numpy array, with dimensions [band, row, col]
    data = source.read()
    print(data.shape)
    rotate_bands=[]
    for nband in range(11):
      array_band=data[nband,:,:].astype(np.uint16)
      rotated_img1=rotate_image(array_band,angle)
      rotate_bands.append(rotated_img1)
    data = np.stack(rotate_bands, axis=0)
    print(data.shape)
    kwargs = source.meta
    kwargs['transform'] = new_transform


    with rasterio.open(outputRaster, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, source.count + 1): #source.count:bands
            #print(rasterio.band(source, i))
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(source, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=source.transform,
                src_crs=source.crs,
                dst_transform=new_transform,
                dst_crs=dst.crs,
                resampling=Resampling.average)
        #dst.write(data)


    return


rotate("/content/drive/MyDrive/data/own data/min_test/minimg_utm.tif", 15, scale=1, outputRaster="/content/drive/MyDrive/data/own data/min_test/mr_minimg_utm.tif")
```

When I read this tif file in python, it looks good:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq1At.png)
But when I open in QGIS, it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXpft.jpg)

Why did this happen? Or does anyone have a better code for rotating a raster?